# Delete listitem after 30 days

Tags: list-item

I would like to create a workflow that deletes an listitem after some time automaticly after for example 30 days or 10 days. Will a workflow be best för this? Or what is the best solution for performing this action?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a workflow or via the Information Management Policy Settings within the list settings

Comment: Hi! Thanks. What kind of workflow should i create for this kind of action ? Kind Regards

Comment: For a workflow you would Pause for a Duration, then Delete Item.

Comment: I am Aware of that but do not know how to perform this action.

Comment: I am not using sharepoint designer for this action. I want to create a workflow in the gui in Sharepoint.

Comment: I'm not aware of anyway to create a workflow through the GUI unless you're using MS Flow, which I would imagine has similar action/conditions for pause/delete.  If you can't create SPD workflows, your best option is probably using the Information Management Policy Settings within the list.

Comment: Alright. I have checked further and created a flow when item added but can not assisgn the worfklow to my dokument library under listname in the flow. Do you know why?